# Detect if point is within rotated rectangles bounds

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I need to detect whether one of rectangles is within the other one.

The title says 'point' - because I wanted to approach it by checking if any of the corners (points) is inside the other rectangle, but it doesn't seem to work so when both rectangles are rotated (I was simply checking if $XY$ of the corner is between $XY$ of two other corners.

Mind you I'm not trying to detect if the objects will collide - I'm trying to detect if one is inside the other.

Here's an image explaining what I'm trying to get done:
The rectangles to the right work flawlessly, but the ones to the left not.

[image]

Comment: How much linear algebra do you know?

Comment: Little to none - otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: The problem is that without knowledge about rotational matrices and such things, your task is going to be super hard. This is exactly why computer science programs at universities always include quite a lot of mathematics - they make programming much much easier.

Comment: Well then, simply rotate the image so that one of the two rectangles is "upright", and you translate the problem into one you can solve!

Comment: All I need is a formula really - I can turn it into code easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328424/point-in-obb-oriented-bounding-box-algorithm

Comment: Your coordinates for the green rectangle are off; it is not a rotated rectangle, but a parallelogram. Try $(-6,-5)$, $(2,-9)$, $(8,3)$, $(0,7)$ instead. Or maybe $(-6,-5)$, $(2,-9)$, $(9,5)$, $(1,9)$.

Answer (score 3):

Basic vector algebra suffices here!

[Rewritten on 2016-06-01, using more general solution with the same "cost", number of multiplications, additions, etc.]

Let's assume the blue *parallelogram* is your bounding box, and the red one (on the right) is the test rectangle -- or, really, any set of points you might wish to test:
[image: Example diagram]

You pick one corner of the parallelogram as its origin ($\vec{b}_0 = (x_0, y_0)$). We don't use the point diagonally opposite. We call one edge $\vec{n}_u = (x_u, y_u)$, and another $\vec{n}_v = (x_v, y_v)$; both start at the $\vec{b}_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ point.

Note that this means the other points on the parallelogram are
$$\vec{b}_w = \vec{b}_0 + \vec{n}_u = (x_0 + x_u, \; y_0 + y_u) \\
\vec{b}_h = \vec{b}_0 + \vec{n}_v = (x_0 + x_v, \; y_0 + y_v)$$
and the unmarked fourth point is at $(x_0 + x_u + x_v, \; y_0 + y_u + y_v)$.

We can transform to a coordinate system that is rotated, translated, scaled, and skewed so that the original parallelogram is at coordinates $(0,0)$-$(1,0)$-$(1,1)$-$(0,1)$. Let's call these coordinates $(u,v)$.

To convert back to ordinary coordinates we use
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_0 + u x_u + v x_v \\
y = y_0 + u y_u + v y_v
\end{cases}$$
Solving the above for $u$ and $v$ gives us the interesting conversion to the $(u,v)$ coordinates:
$$\begin{cases}
u = \frac{(x - x_0)y_v - (y - y_0)x_v}{x_u y_v - y_u x_v} \\
v = \frac{(y - y_0)x_u - (x - x_0)y_u}{x_u y_v - y_u x_v} \\
\end{cases}$$

Combining the conversion with the limits shown earlier, we can condense the test. Do note that the divisor (or limit),
$$L = x_u y_v - y_u x_v$$
may be positive or negative. A point $(x,y)$ is inside our bounding parallelogram if and only if
$$L \gt 0: \begin{cases}
0 \le (x - x_0)y_v - (y - y_0)x_v \le L \\
0 \le (y - y_0)x_u - (x - x_0)y_u \le L
\end{cases} \\
L \lt 0: \begin{cases}
0 \le (y - y_0)x_v - (x - x_0)y_v \le -L \\
0 \le (x - x_0)y_u - (y - y_0)x_u \le -L
\end{cases}$$
$L \ne 0$ unless one or both edges are zero length, or if they are parallel. In fact, $L$ is actually [the area of the parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning); zero $L$ means the parallelogram has zero area (vanishes).

Now, I originally had a "simpler" test using direct projection (dot product, also known as projection product), but it only works if the edges are perpendicular to each other. This one works for squares, rectangles, and parallelograms -- and has exactly the same number of multiplications and additions; only the sign check is extra -- so this one is clearly *better* choice.

---

Let's look at OP's example bounding box, with corners at $(1,6)$, $(-6,-5)$, $(2,-9)$, and $(9,3)$. I'll choose, arbitrarily,
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{b}_0 = (-6, -5) \\
\vec{b}_w = (1, 6) \\
\vec{b}_h = (2, -9)
\end{cases} \iff \left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll}
x_0 = -6, & y_0 = -5 \\
x_u = 7, & y_u = 11 \\
x_v = 8, & y_v = -4 \end{array}\right.$$

This means that the fourth point is actually $(-6+7+8,-5+11-4) = (9,2)$, and not $(9,3)$; OP's bounding region is a quadrilateral, not a parallelogram. (Because $\vec{n}_u\cdot\vec{n}_v = 7\cdot8-11\cdot4 = 12 \ne 0$, the edges are not perpendicular; the box is not rectangular either way.)

So, assuming the fourth corner of the bounding parallelogram is at $(9,2)$, we can test for some points. We have
$$L = 7(-4) - 8(11) = -116$$and therefore the inclusion tests are
$$\begin{cases}
0 \; \le \; (y + 5)8 + (x + 6)4 \; \le \; 116\\
0 \; \le \; (x + 6)11 - (y + 5)7 \; \le \; 116
\end{cases}$$

Let's check point $(x,y) = (12, 16)$ first. (We know it has to be outside.) 
$$\begin{cases}
(y+5)8 + (x+6)4 = (16+5)8 + (12+6)4 = 240 \\
(x+6)11 - (y+5)7 = (12+6)11 - (16+5)7 = 51
\end{cases}$$
the first is greater than $116$, so the point is definitely outside.

Let's check point $(x,y) = (3,3)$. Remember, OP's diagram has a quadrilateral, which should be fixed to put the fourth corner at $(9,2)$, to make it a quadrilateral.
$$\begin{cases}
(y+5)8 + (x+6)4 = (3+5)8 + (3+6)4 = 100 \\
(x+6)11 - (y+5)7 = (3+6)11 - (3+5)7 = 43
\end{cases}$$
But yes, point $(3,3)$ is inside the fixed quadrilateral, too.

If you have an arbitrary quadrilateral, an arbitrary polygon (convex or concave), there are other methods one can do to determine whether a point is inside it or not. Many of these cases have been asked and answered before, and each of them have different efficient numerical solutions, so combining them all into a single answer is not sensible.

---

Here is some pseudocode to help with implementation.

Let's assume we have variables

```
x0,y0     # b0, the origin corner of the bounding parallelogram
xw,yw     # bw, another corner of the bounding parallelogram
xh,yh     # bh, the third corner of the bounding parallelogram
```

Each time the above change, I would precalculate five variables:

```
xu = xw - x0
yu = yw - y0
xv = xh - x0
yv = yh - y0
L = xu * yv - xv * yu
if L < 0:
    L = -L
    xu = -xu
    yv = -yv
else:
    xv = -xv
    yu = -yu
end if
```

The above negates the constants when necessary, so that only one case, one set of tests, is left: `0 <= (x-x0)*yv + (y-y0)*xv <= L` and `0 <= (x-x0)*yu + (y-y0)*xu <= L`. This means the test for each point `(x,y)` is

```
u = (x - x0)*yv + (y - y0)*xv
if (u < 0 || u > L):
    return OUTSIDE
else:
    v = (x - x0)*yu + (y - y0)*xu
    if (v < 0 || v > L):
        return OUTSIDE
    else:
        return INSIDE
    end if
end if
```

which boils down to four multiplications, four additions and two subtractions, and four comparisons, maximum, to determine point inclusion in the parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks - that was more than enough, I'll get into coding tommorow and I'll let you know.

Comment: The 2nd formula is somewhat unclear to me - where did you get yw, y0 and such from?

Or is it formula for comparing 2 rectangles, by calculating their bounding box.

Comment: @Netheous: The bounding box is determined by three points: $\vec{b}_0 = (x_0, y_0)$, $\vec{b}_w = (x_w, y_w)$, and $\vec{b}_h = (x_h, y_h)$. The latter two are opposite corner points of the box, and $\vec{b}_0$ is the corner in between. Let's say your green box is the bounding box. Then, you can pick e.g. $\vec{b}_0 = (-6,-5)$, $\vec{b}_w = (1,6)$, and $\vec{b}_h = (2,-9)$. That means $x_0 = -6$, $y_0 = -5$, $x_w = 1$, $y_w = 6$, $x_h = 2$, and $y_h = -9$. The point to test is $\vec{p} = (x, y)$, say $(3,3)$, so $x=3$, $y=3$. You calculate $u$ and $v$ based on these as shown.

Comment: Ah, now I get it - it would be more clear to me if you simply signed xw as bwx

Comment: The only issue I'm having now is that it works almost perfectly, but not for all corners.

It says that 3 and 4 are out of bounds (which is correct) but it also says that 1 and 2 are within bounds (whereas only 1 is within bounds): as seen here:
http://puu.sh/pd1cL/c56e3e36ac.jpg

Comment: Sorry for not giving you much to work with and thanks for being very patient with me, somewhat it works for 1st corner of the green rectangle and for the 3rd, 4th but it doesn't seem to work as well for 2nd.

Here's code, hope you can make any sense of it (it's lua).
http://puu.sh/pd1Yd/a21b8e7635.txt

Comment: Sorry again, here's proper image showing which corner returned it being within bounds: http://puu.sh/pd6h6/9fe67d2ceb.jpg

Comment: Your bounding box is not a rectangle, it is a parallelogram, as I commented on your question -- at least the numbers shown are not for a rectangle. That is, the angles are not 90 degrees.

Comment: Okay, here's a tiny update: http://puu.sh/pd7mj/3282c375c8.jpg

Comment: True and false mark wheter U and V are between 0-1

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with how I've turned formula into code?

Comment: @Netheous: No, the issue is that your "box" is not. It is not a rectangle, or even a parallelogram; it is just a four-sided polygon. I rewrote my answer to cater for squares, rectangles, and parallelograms -- all four-sided polygons with two parallel sides. (My earlier answer assumed the sides were perpendicular, and would give incorrect answers if they are not.) If you actually need an inclusion test for an arbitrary quadrilateral -- four-sided polygon, there is *yet another* method to do so.

Comment: Have you seen the new image I've sent?: http://puu.sh/pd7mj/3282c375c8.jpg

If we can't work anything out for this then I'll simply rotate both rectangles so one of them has angles set to ( 0, 0, 0 ) as someone previously suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40631/discussion-between-netheous-and-nominal-animal).